# Routing to same page with anchors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react router and currently implementing a page with navigation.
The top part is navigation followed by content part.

Currently when someone clicks on `localhost:8080/page` it renders a component in the content part. 
On click on one of the nav items page redirects to `localhost:8080/page#my-anchor` also the content below renders another component.

When clicking back button, the URL changes to `localhost:8080/page` but the content doesn't get updated.

How to handle the update of content with browser back & forward buttons?

Comment: Did you mention `exact` in routes declaration? Which version are you using?

Comment: yes I am using `exact` in route declaration. version is `4.1.1`